# makecert tool issue

Tags: certificate, makecert

I am confused about the following concepts in makecert tool. Especially about what means location (-sr parameter) and store (-ss parameter). I read and get my confusion from [this link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bfsktky3(VS.80).aspx), I tried to find tutorials about what means "location" and "store", but finding nothing. Could anyone help to clarify please?

Answer (score 1):

Those are parts of the specification for how Windows locates the certificate storage.  The `-sr` *location* parameter tells the tool which certificate store to use: either **currentuser** to store it for the user, or **localmachine** to store it for everyone on the machine. The `-ss` parameter let's you give a name for a particular store, so you could, for example, have

```
-sr currentuser -ss moe
-sr localmachine -ss moe
```

and have two different named stores -- one for the current user, one for the machine -- or have

```
-sr currentuser -ss moe
-sr currentuser -ss curly
```

and have two different stores for just the current user.

Comment: Thanks Charlie, 1. another stupid question, any means to see current named stores for currentuser and localmachine? 2. I am still confused whether certificates are managed linearly (a linear named store) or in a hierarchy way?

Comment: Hierarchy way I mean certificate is managed under two layers, the first layer is currentuser/localmachine, and under the node of currentuser or localmachine, there could be named stores. Any comments or ideas?

Comment: The way I understand it is that it is a two-layer hierarchy, that is, there is a store for currentuser with (potentially) a bunch of named stores.  I wouldn't depend on that, though: give it a try.

Comment: Thanks Charlie, are there any tools or commands to check on my current Windows Server 2003, whether currentuser and localmachine store are created, and which sub-stores are in them?

Comment: George, I've got no idea; I don't even have a Windows box accessible.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if it exists in windows server 2003 but in win XP i use the Microsoft Management Console to see all available certificates in windows store.

Type 'mmc' in run (from start menu) to open the MS management console.
Then go to 'File' menu and choose 'Add/Remove snap-in'.
Press Add button and now you can choose one of the user, service or computer account.

When you do this you will perfectly understand the diference between -sr and -ss option.